# aws-xray-sdk nodejs lambda to lambda xray is not sampling the traces on second lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-xray

**Flow is like below:**

Xray is running in Automatic Mode. Lambda functions are written in Nodejs.

**Synchronous calls:**
API Gateway => Main Lambda => child lambda1 (which calls external api)=> child lambda2 ((which calls one other API)

Main lambda will wait for child lambda1 response, child lambda 1 will wait for child lambda2 response. After these two tasks I make db calls.

After I inject xray tracing in service map I can't see child lambdas( I can see Main lambda and db calls).I  am using all defaults not configured any custom sampling rules.

When I enabled Debug Logs:

*DEBUG  Ignoring flush on subsegment **************. Associated segment is marked as not sampled.*

In cloudwatch/xray servicemap I couldn't see the Child lambda1, child lambda 2 related tracing.

Tracing is enabled in all lambdas.

**Xray node sdk version :**

"aws-xray-sdk": "^3.3.3"

```js
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
const aws = AWSXRay.captureAWS(require('aws-sdk'));
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('https'), true);
```

Can someone point me in right direction or share the resources which can help on this.

Answer (score 0):

In trace graph (not service graph), is db calls node in the same page with main Lambda node? If yes, please follow [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-xray.html) to enable tracing for your 3 Lambda functions